# How do I make WebHelp show help for a specific topic instead of the index?

Tags: delphi, lazarus

I am in the process of adding help to my Lazarus application. I am using WebHelp rather than CHM help to aid in cross-platform utilisation.

WebHelp essentially uses a pair of html pages within a frameset - an index on the left, and the associated topic on the right. To open the help system at a specific page in the web browser, it is called as:

```
file:///path_to_help_files/index.htm#specific.htm
```

The Lazarus form has a THTMLHelpDatabase component, and a THTMLBrowserHelpViewer component as per the instructions at http://wiki.freepascal.org/Add_Help_to_Your_Application.

Individual components have their HelpType set to htKeyword, and the HelpKeyword set to HTML/index.htm or HTML/index.htm#something.htm

Whatever I enter, the help files are only opened at the default page (i.e. index.htm).

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get the help pages to open at a specific page?

[I can't specify a HelpKeyword of HTML/something.htm because that would omit the topic index. Effectively, I have to go through index.htm to get the frameset appearing.]

Comment: What URLs are being passed to the browser?

Comment: The URL being received by the browser is:  path_to_file/index.html   In other words, the #something.htm has been stripped off the end (probably some validation in the Lazarus code!).

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution, but it is a bit clunky, so if anyone has a better idea, I'd like to hear it.

Essentially, I've created a redirect for something.html that looks like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Something</title>
    <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=index.htm#something.htm">
  </head>
  <body>
    Redirect to index.html
  </body>
</html>
```

I then point the relevant Lazarus control at HTML/something.html in HelpKeyword so that when help is called, it redirects to the correct URL. (And yes, I am using a .html extension for the redirects, while the real files have .htm extensions - forced by the help authoring application).

The real hassle about this is that I've got to have a redirect file for every topic in the help system that I want to access directly from the Lazarus application.